# How do I animate the appearance of a circle or rectangle in a Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Help please, I'm new to flutter. How can I animate the appearance of a circle or rectangle so that when the button is pressed, not just the circle changes to a square, but with animation. The new element is fired from a small size to the current one in 1 second. To do this, I use AnimatedContainer, I don't quite understand how to work with it, I think that you can pass the "_checked" variable to it, but I don't know how, if there are other ways, I will be very grateful, here is my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(
          new MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,// скрываем надпись debug
              home: new Scaffold(
                  body: new MyButton()
              )
          )
      );
    }
    
    class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      MyButtonState createState() => MyButtonState();
    }
    
    class MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
      bool isVisibleCircle = false;
      bool isVisibleRectangle = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
            child: new Column( children: <Widget> [
              new Row (
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget> [
                  new TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isVisibleCircle = true;
                          isVisibleRectangle = false; });},
                      child: Text('Red Circle'),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
                        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),)),
    
                  new TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isVisibleRectangle = true;
                          isVisibleCircle = false; });},
                      child: Text('Blue Rectangle'),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),)),
                ]),
                if (isVisibleCircle) new Circle(),
                if (isVisibleRectangle) new Rectangle(),
                ]));
      }
    }
    
    class Circle extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CircleState createState() => CircleState();
}

class CircleState extends State<Circle> {
bool _checked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedContainer(
      width: _checked ? 100 : 300.0,
      height: _checked ? 100 :300.0,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
    );
  }
}

class Rectangle extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RectangleState createState() => RectangleState();
}

class RectangleState extends State<Rectangle> {
  bool _checked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedContainer(
      width: _checked ? 100 : 300.0,
      height: _checked ? 100 :300.0,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
    );
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

please have a look

```
class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyButtonState createState() => MyButtonState();
}

class MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  bool isVisibleCircle = false;
  bool isVisibleRectangle = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: new Column( children: <Widget> [
          new Row (
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget> [
                new TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isVisibleCircle = true;
                        isVisibleRectangle = false; });},
                    child: Text('Red Circle'),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),)),

                new TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isVisibleRectangle = true;
                        isVisibleCircle = false; });},
                    child: Text('Blue Rectangle'),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),)),
              ]),
            Circle(isVisibleCircle),
            Rectangle(isVisibleRectangle),
        ]));
  }
}

class Circle extends StatefulWidget {
  bool checked = false;
  Circle(this.checked);
  @override
  CircleState createState() => CircleState();
}

class CircleState extends State<Circle> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedContainer(
      width: widget.checked ? 300 : 0,
      height: widget.checked ?  300 : 0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: SizedBox(height: 100, width: 100,),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

}

class Rectangle extends StatefulWidget {
  bool checked = false;
  Rectangle(this.checked);
  @override
  RectangleState createState() => RectangleState();
}

class RectangleState extends State<Rectangle> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedContainer(
      width: widget.checked ? 300 : 0,
      height: widget.checked ? 300 :0,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
    );
  }
}
```